# Codeigniter unable to load the requested file: template.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, view

I have created a template folder that contains header.php, head.php, foot.php and footer.php in views folder. I tried to load the template folder and my login.php by using this code below:

```
$this->load->view('template', array(
        'title'     =>   'Login',
        'view_file' => 'login',
    ));
```

and it gives me an error like this: Unable to load the requested file: template.php, I am not sure what I did wrong. So, any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the template.php file inside template folder ,and in case you want to add header and footer do like this:

```
$this->load->view('template/header');
$this->load->view('template/template', array(
        'title'     =>   'Login',
        'view_file' => 'login',
    ));
$this->load->view('template/footer');
```

Comment: yes you are right @Ketan Solanki, thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

For those still struggling with this error: the permissions on both the view file and its directory need to be readable. If your permissions are too restrictive CodeIgniter will be unable to read your view file and return this error.